# HTML Canvas fill not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Html:
HTML:

```
<canvas id="main"  height="1000" width="1500"></canvas>
```

JS

```
  var c = document.getElementById("main");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(200,300);
  ctx.lineTo(800,0);
  ctx.moveTo(800,0);
  ctx.lineTo(1500,300);
  ctx.moveTo(1500,300);
  ctx.lineTo(200,300);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle="#8ED6FF";
  ctx.fill();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THPmr/221/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kushal812/THPmr/222/)
Updated code

```
  var c = document.getElementById("main");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(200,300);
  ctx.lineTo(800,0);
  ctx.lineTo(1500,300);
  ctx.lineTo(200,300);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fillStyle="#8ED6FF";
  ctx.fill();
```

You dont need to move to same point again as you are already on that point .. so thats why it wasnt working

Comment: You dont need to move to same point again as you are already on that point .. so thats why it wasnt working

Comment: @Kushal You simply said "you don't need to". That doesn't help at all. If that's what made it not work, say that. And explain why. Don't say "it didn't work because you did this", say why the thing he did made it not work.

Answer (score 2):

### Sub-paths

This will create (clear) a new main path, so far so good:

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

The `moveTo()` call will create a new *sub-path* on the main path, here:

```
ctx.moveTo(200,300);
ctx.lineTo(800,0);
```

and here:

```
ctx.moveTo(800,0);
ctx.lineTo(1500,300);
```

and here:

```
ctx.moveTo(1500,300);
ctx.lineTo(200,300);
```

And finally, this will connect first point in path with the last point (in this case they are already overlapping):

```
ctx.closePath();
```

Since you now have three sub-paths which represents three unconnected lines, as they all have their own sub-paths, there is no way to fill them as a single shape. And they will not connect simply by having their points overlapping.

### Create a continuous line with a single sub-path

You need to make a *continuous* line on the *current sub-path*. The `lineTo()` method will continue from the last point in the current path/sub-path to the coordinate it specifies, so to make a single shape using a single sub-path, you just add a new point to the sub-path by doing:

```
ctx.beginPath();       // new main path
ctx.moveTo(200,300);   // creates a new sub-path, start point (200, 300)
ctx.lineTo(800,0);     // line from (200, 300) to (800, 0), current point now: (800,0)
ctx.lineTo(1500,300);  // line from (800, 0) to (1500, 300)
//ctx.lineTo(200,300); // not needed because:
ctx.closePath();       // will connect (1500,300) to (200,300) on the current sub-path
```

Using `fill()` will also close the path, internally and non-permanent, as it's impossible to fill an open path assuming it has > 2 points (it saves you a line of code, but not very important, just note that `stoke()` does *not* close the path for you internally).

---

*Also, a [tip not many are aware of](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/tr9rv4ej/): if you intended to draw more closed shapes in the same `fillStyle`, you could continue with `moveTo()` after the `closePath()` to create a new sub-path without the need of using `fill()`/`beginPath()` first..*